# Пониежние версии PHP XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Как понизить версию PHP до 5.4 без переустановки всего пакета XAMPP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не поддерживается. XAMPP предполагает что все компоненты от тестированы и работают вместе. Чтобы понизить версию PHP надо переустановить весь пакет только старой версии.

Конечно вы можете просто удалить установленый PHP и скопировать на его место новый, но никто вам не гарантирует что это будет работать. Вы потеряете гарантированую совместимость, вы будете ловить глюки и возится с совместимостью сами.